# Cant package my robot

Tags: robocode

I'm trying to package a robocode robot created with .Net but it does not appear on my list under the "Package robot or team" window.

I am using VisualStudio 2013 with .Net 2.0 to create the DLL. I have the DLL in my robots folder and I can select it when playing battles. However it does not appear on the Package robots list (only teams robots appear).

Am I missing a step?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Just realized it is not possible to package .Net robots https://sourceforge.net/p/robocode/discussion/116458/thread/9a83c21e/